# Fancybox2 groups using href

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

After switching from Fancybox 1 to version 2 grouping does not work anymore. I have the following HTML:

```
<a id="preview_1" class="preview" rel="xxl" href="this.php?picNo=1">
  <img id="previewImage_1" class="previewImage" src="1.jpg" />
</a>
<a id="preview_2" class="preview" rel="xxl" href="this.php?picNo=2">
  <img id="previewImage_2" class="previewImage" src="2.jpg" />
</a>
....
```

Note that I do not use the URL of the images to be shown by Fancybox as URL above. This is because I want to have a suitable fallback for users who have JavaScript turned off.
Instead I create the fancybox using this code:

```
$("a.preview").each(function() {
  var imgID = this.id.replace("preview_", "");
  $(this).fancybox({
    "href": imageURL[imgID], // this array is set somewhere else
    "type": "image",
  });
});
```

This works fine in Fancybox 1. When I click on one of the links, Fancybox shows arrows so that I can click throw the group of images. However, in Fancybox 2 the images are no longer grouped. If I click on one of the links only the associated image is shown, not the others of this group (having the same "rel").

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the `.each()` method to bind elements to fancybox (v2.x), it somehow binds each element as a separated *group*.

I haven't analyzed completely the script to tell you exactly what is going on.

But what I can say is that you can completely drop the `.each()` method and get the value of `imgID` dynamically within the `beforeLoad` callback. Then set the corresponding `href` from the array like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("a.preview").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            var imgID = $(this.element).attr("id").replace("preview_", "") - 1;
            this.href = imageURL[imgID];
        },
        type: "image"
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we need to *subtract* `1` to the ID since javascript *indexes* start with `0`

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1rzt0k0o/)**

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.x, however it works equally well with fancybox v1.3.4 using the proper callbacks and selectors :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("a.preview").fancybox({
        onStart: function (currentArray, currentIndex) {
            var imgID = $(".preview").eq(currentIndex).attr("id").replace("preview_", "") - 1;
            this.href = imageURL[imgID];
        },
        type: "image"
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ts39kxza/)**

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.

Just a note to the note: I do not need to substract 1, because "preview_1" matches to imgURL[1] in my case. So this worked well in the code of my example.